# How to display plain text attachments inline with mu4e?

Tags: email, mu4e

I'm using mu4e as my email client and it works fine for the most part.  However, I'm working with patches sent via email very often and mu4e won't display inlined attachments as part of the email body, which is very inconvenient.  Instead it lists them as attachments that I can awkwardly open in Emacs with a little too many steps.

Is there a way to let mu4e display certain attachments **inline** with the email text?

(I would also like attachments of type `text/plain` or `text/x-patch` to be displayed inline, even when their `Content-Disposition` is `attachment`, but that's optional.)

It is especially annoying when I get an email with an embedded short patch snippet, with the body text continuing afterward.  The snippet is cut out of context and having to do `A-e 2 RET` is taking me out of the email.

Comment: Assuming that this can't simply be enabled with a `(setq ...)` or something similarly easy, would you consider a feature request to the maintainer?

Comment: An issue is now reported: https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/942

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to let mu4e display certain attachments **inline** with the email text?

The short answer is "no."

`mu` concatenates all `text/plain` parts to form the body of a message--- both for indexing and viewing messages. As far as I can tell **only** `text/plain` gets this treatment and since this is done by `mu` you cannot change this behavior in `mu4e`. (See [`static void accumulate_text_part (MuMsg *msg, MuMsgPart *part, GString **gstrp)`](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/master/lib/mu-msg-part.c#L131) for the code.)

The *location* of a part with `Content-Disposition: inline` is lost when `mu` accumulates text parts to build a message body, and so one cannot display *any* part (except for `text/plain`) truely inline.

It should be possible to display `text/plain`, `text/x-patch`, or any other attachment at the end of the body similar to the way `mu4e` displays images when `mu4e-view-show-images` is set to `t`. (This would require writing a bit of elisp to extend `mu4e`. I think I know how to do it, so let me know if you're interested.)

I learned all this by reading the [`mu` source code](https://github.com/djcb/mu/). Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if this is what you're looking for, but I open attachments in emacs with `A-e` from inside the message.

More info: http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/MSGV-Actions.html

Comment: no, that's not what I meant.  I do that too now, but I find it awkward.  I really want plain text attachments to be displayed inline.  It's especially annoying when the body text continues after the plain text attachment.  Right now the attachment is just cut from the body.